# How can i check real running time?

Tags: matlab

I am learning algorithm using matlab.
I used the instruction; tic and toc.
In my opinion, however, these instructions are just calculating elapsed time. How can i find real running time only in the running state? 
no in the waiting or ready state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at [`cputime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cputime.html).  However, this is **not** the recommended way to calculate time for a set of statements.  It's better that you use `tic/toc`, but I personally recommend [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) for a proper measurement of time of a function.

See here for a list of reasons why using `cputime` is not recommended: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html

However, if you don't want to read that all, the takeaway message from the link I referenced is this:

> Although you can measure performance using the `cputime` function, the `timeit` or `tic` and `toc` functions are better for this purpose. Generally for CPU-intensive calculations that run on Microsoft® Windows® machines, the elapsed time from `cputime` and from `tic` and `toc` are close in value, ignoring any first-time costs. There are cases, however, that show a significant difference between these functions. For example, in the case of a Pentium 4 with hyperthreading running Windows, there can be a significant difference between the values returned by cputime versus tic and toc.
>
> Like `tic` and `toc`, `timeit` provides more reliable results than `cputime`. However, the `timeit` function also considers first-time costs.